# Python text file into .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, thank you for reading my post. I'm having a particular issue when parsing data from a .txt file and putting it into a .csv file. From the text document I'm trying to draw the hostname and loopback address from a router config file, then put it in separate columns in an excel sheet. Instead, when I added the " outFile.write("".join(buffer))", it's a jumbled mess in the excel sheet and it also adds strings that the print function didn't.

Here is the code:

```
inFile = open("Data.txt")
outFile = open("result.csv", "w")
buffer = []
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in inFile:
        buffer.append(line)
        if line.startswith ("hostname"):
                print (line) 
                outFile.write("".join(buffer))
        elif line.startswith("interface Loopback"):
                print (line)
                print (next(inFile))
                outFile.write("".join(buffer))
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Here is the text file

```
[spoiler]
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname cisco1841
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 51200 warnings
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone Arizona -7
ip cef
!
!
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.1.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.3.1
!
ip dhcp pool Inside
network 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server 205.171.3.65 4.2.2.1
default-router 10.10.1.1
!
ip dhcp pool Wireless
import all
network 10.10.3.0 255.255.255.0
dns-server 205.171.3.65 4.2.2.1
default-router 10.10.3.1
lease 3
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
username xxxxxxx privilege 15 secret 5 xxxxxxxxxx
!
bridge irb
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
description Inside LAN
ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
duplex auto
speed auto
[/spoiler]
```

Comment: Please specify details about what *exactly* you want the output to be like! What exactly is the problem? Based on your question, your script seems to work, but we can't tell whats the expected output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to open your .csv in excel, it's probably not going to be very readable. 
csv stands for comma separated values, and your output has no commas, but a lot of whitespace and newlines- excel can't really be expected to handle those. Here's what the output of your program is (plus newlines):

```
hostname cisco1841

interface Loopback0

ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.255
```

You can format your output more correctly by adding commas to your output file in place of the spaces that are already there. For the ip address line you want to grab, it's harder since that has a space in its name as well. I solved this by just grabbing the first ipAddress listed in that line- if you want the other one or both it's an easy fix. I also removed the buffer you were using and "keepCurrentResultSet" because there's really no need for them that I can see.

```
inFile = open("text.txt")
outFile = open("result.csv", "w")
for line in inFile:
        if line.startswith ("hostname"):
                outFile.write(line.replace(' ',','))
        elif line.startswith("interface Loopback"):
                outFile.write(line.replace(' ',','))
                ipAddrLine = next(inFile)
                ipAddress = ipAddrLine.split(' ')[2:3]
                outFile.write('ip address,' + ','.join(ipAddress))
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

That gives this output, which should be considerd valid .csv format by excel:

```
hostname,cisco1841
interface,Loopback0
ip address,10.10.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = []
```

`buffer` is a list. For every line in the original file you append to it:

```
for line in inFile:
    buffer.append(line)
```

So it will always contain a list of all lines already read.

```
outFile.write("".join(buffer))
```

You then write the whole `buffer` into the file each time you find a relevant line. But because `buffer` is a list of all lines read, you basically repeatedly write the concatenation of all previously read lines into the file.

You should instead write the line:

```
outFile.write(line)
```

You do not need to advance the file iterator here: `print (next(inFile))`. The for loop is already doing this.

If you make these changes, the script will filter the lines starting with `"hostname"` or `"interface Loopback"`. `buffer` is not needed at all. If you actually want the line following `"interface Loopback"`, then you should substitute

```
print (next(inFile))
```

with

```
line = next(inFile)
```

However this seems not to be what you want. I do not really know what you want to do though.

So my guess would be that you want to put the hostname and ip address into two columns and then maybe iterate through many files. In that case you could read in the whole file (assuming it is not too long) and use regular expressions to filter what you need. Then you can write the result with the help of `csv`:

```
import csv
import re

outFile = open("result.csv", "w")
outFileCsv = csv.writer(outFile)
outFileCsv.writerow(["hostname", "loopback ip"])

for filename in ["Data.txt"]: # Add more files here
    try:
        inFile = open(filename).read()
    except IOError:
        print("Could not read {0}".format(filename))
        continue
    try:
        hostname = re.search("\nhostname (.*)\n", inFile).group(1)
        loopback_ip = re.search("\ninterface Loopback.*\n(?!\ninterface).*ip address ([0-9\\.]*)", inFile).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        print("No match in {0}".format(filename))
        continue    
    outFileCsv.writerow([hostname, loopback_ip])

outFile.close()
```